# Creating simple slideDown and slideUp animation in css

Tags: css, animation

I have some css like this

```
  .top-over {
    position: absolute;
    top: 205px;
    z-index: 55;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
  }
  
  @keyframes slideDown {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-420px);
    }

    100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }

  .slideDown {
    -webkit-animation-name: slideDown;
    animation-name: slideDown;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    visibility: visible !important;
    z-index: 50;
  }
```

You will see that i have two classes slideDown and .top-over
.slideDown work just ok, but on .top-over it just jumps no slide effect, does anybody knows what i need to correct that this works to slideUp, thanks

Comment: `translateY(-420)` . A unit is missing here. And you don't need vendor prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Several notes:

- you might want to remove the -webkit- prefixed values since they're not needed in this case. In cases where they are needed, they shouldn't be used either.
  Both transform and animation are supported by every modern browser without prefixes.
- use the same units across an animation - choose either px or %, not both.
- you should post your html code as well. Please make it as minimal as possible and share your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .slider {
        overflow-y: hidden;
        max-height: 500px; /* approximate max height */
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: .5s;
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
    }
        .slider.closed {
            max-height: 0;
        }
</style>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="slider">Some content here....</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

<%--Hope this will work.Thanks in advance--%>

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //You can use Predifined Function in JQuery
    $(function () {
        $('#trCaptcha').slideUp();
        $('#trCaptcha').slideDown();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need pure css, not Jquery

Comment: try to add context to your answer, instead of just copy pasting code. Also the question is for how to create a css animation, if you propose another solution try to give a solid context to why jquery in this instance is the right answer.